# Общая подстрока из подряд идущих

Tags: python, строки

Подается N строк из маленьких английских букв (1 ≤ N ≤ 10) . Нужно найти самую большую общую подстроку.
В первой строке входных данных записано число N. Далее N строк (Длины строк от 1 до 10 000) 
Вывести наибольшую общую подстроку

**Тесты**
**Входные данные:**
abacaba 
mycabarchive 
acabistrue 
**Выходные данные:** 
cab

---

Я смог решить эту задачу только при условии, что N не превышает 2. Реализовал проверку 2 строк с сдвигом одной из них на одну позицию на каждой итерации. Таким образом я смог получить общую подстроку из 2 строк. Но что делать, если строк больше чем 2?

```
def podstroka(s1, s2):
    count = 0
    check, result = "", ""
    while count != len(s1):
        for i in range(len(s1)):
            if i + count == len(s2):
                break
            if s1[i] == s2[i + count]:
                check += s1[i]
            else:
                check = ""
            if len(check) > len(result):
                result = check
        check = ""
        count += 1
    print(result)



n = int(input())
if n == 1:
    print(input())
else:
    str = input()
    str2 = input()
    if len(str2) < len(str):
        temp = str
        str = str2
        str2 = temp
        del temp
    podstroka(str, str2)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892931/longest-common-substring-from-more-than-two-strings-python

Comment: @GrAnd Код с этой страницы не проходит по времени